# := assigning in multiple environments

Tags: r, scope, data.table

I have two data tables which I left join in a function. I reassign the values of one column using `:=`, but it changes the value of that column both in that function and in the global environment (see code)

```
library(data.table)

# Example data
dt1 <- data.table(letters=letters[1:6],
                  value=1:6 + 0.0)
dt2 <- data.table(letters=c("b", "e"),
                  value=rnorm(2))

# Define a function so we perform := in separate environment
f <- function(df1, df2) {
  df1[df2, on="letters", value:=value-i.value]
}

# Run the function
f(dt1, dt2)

# Surprised to find it's updated dt1's value column
# despite dt1 being in a different environment
dt1
```

Is there a way of getting `:=` to assign only in the environment it's being used in? Or at least so it doesn't affect the environment I'm working in...

Comment: See `?data.table::copy`

Comment: Or `df1[df2, on="letters", .(value=value-i.value)]`

Comment: @Aurèle Thanks. That code seems to work, except it's now an inner rather than left join

Comment: Then maybe `copy(df1)[df2, on="letters", value:=value-i.value]`

Comment: Thanks, that works. I misunderstood why you mentioned copy earlier - thought it was because it talked about := using references (which is also helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `copy` the object in the body of the function, before modifying it by reference:

```
f <- function(df1, df2) {
  copy(df1)[df2, on="letters", value:=value-i.value]
}
```